# Restkit results.array is valid but then xcode is wrong

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, mapping, restkit

If you look at this image you can see that the response mapping of my restkit POST returns an array of 15 mapped objects from a json blob that contains the 15 objects.

However if you look at the mapped array result you can see that Xcode thinks its 15 sub objects with valid addresses but thinks its a key/value pair... instead being my custom object.

Any thoughts to why this is being so weird in xcode?  I would think these would be valid objects?[image]

Comment: Are you actually having a problem, or it's just the debugger view which is confusing (and potentially wrong / not a truly meaningful interpretation)?

Comment: well the debugger is wrong and later down the road in my app Im having issues reading from this array. (aka I get objects with nil properties throughout) So this debugger output seems to be my first initial clue to why the result array is invalid.

Comment: So you probably want to turn on trace logging, describe the actual problem and show some code and log output